# Using SQL Server and mongodb with Repository pattern in node.js

Tags: sql-server, node.js, mongodb, express, dependency-injection

I try to implement dependency injection with repository pattern in expressJS. I want to achieve that using two different repository types (mongodb and SQL Server ) but one controller.

When app starts, I should choose one repository type (for example SQL Server repository) which is used by application. So I don't want to create different controllers for every repository types.

How can I do that? Is there any suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

I suspect you are coming from a statically-typed languages like C# or Java in which using one class over another is somewhat convoluted since their interface must match. Keep in mind that in languages like JavaScript that are dynamically typed using one class or another is easy; there is little required ceremony to use one or the other, it's mostly up to you to make sure both classes implement the required functionality.

```
var dbProv = (config == "sql") ? new SqlProv() : new mongoProv();
dbProv.getAll();
```

Comment: Thank you! As you said I'm coming from C#. Okkay I get the point, but I can't still imagine how I can implement insert process or complex queries in two different repositories? Should I use model binding?

Comment: There is nothing inherit in JavaScript or any other language to make this simple. This is a tough problem and I've seen many people fail at writing a "universal data access layer" more often than not. It is doable but, it is not easy. I wouldn't go that route unless you really need to.